# imgur API - lots of credits left but ImgurClientRateLimitError: Rate-limit exceeded

Tags: python, imgur

i'm using the python imgur client to do some uploads but i'm getting

```
ImgurClientRateLimitError: Rate-limit exceeded!
```

I've done nowhere near 500 api requests an hour and this is what my current credits look like:

```
{   u'ClientLimit': 12500,
    u'ClientRemaining': 12500,
    u'UserLimit': 500,
    u'UserRemaining': 500,
    u'UserReset': 1429698684
}
```

I've gone over the docs here https://api.imgur.com/#limits but can't find anything to indicate why i would be getting rate limit error.

Does anyone know why i'm getting this?

my specific upload call looks like

```
x = imgur_client.upload_from_url(url, config=None, anon=True)
```

-------- update -----
Here's screenshots of stats in mashape. i don't see how i could possibly be anywhere near the limit.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Oulh8tn.png]
[image: http://i.imgur.com/OFQNZwe.png]

Comment: It means taht you reached the API rate limit (that is, 12500 requests/day).

Comment: pls see update to question with screenshots of my usage graphs in mashape.

Comment: how do you know what your current credit is? what did you browse to or what command did you run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those encountering this, the solution is to make sure you send your mashape key in your HTTP headers.

At the time i made this post, it wasn't supported in the default imgur python library but it is now.

https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython/blob/master/imgurpython/client.py#L76

Comment: So is mashape now required to use imgurpython for requests that require authentication (i.e., posting a photo)?

Comment: (signing up for mashape worked for me too -- I had to put in a credit card)